# Ubuntu 18.04 E: Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu

Im trying to install webpagetest agent using the ubuntu installer script here https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/wptagent-install

On a fresh Azure Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image, it works no problem.

However, I need to install it on a fresh VPSCity Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image (which is located in NZ).  When Run the installer on this it fails with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate
```

I have done the following prior to this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

cat /etc/apt/sources.list

gives

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

I have seen some posts saying I need to enable multiverse. How do I do this via SSH command line session?

Is it normal that two different Ubuntu 18.04 LTS servers are so different?

I also tried it on 20.04, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for the package on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=ttf-mscorefonts-installer) you'll notice that the package is in the **multiverse** [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), which is missing in your sources.list.

You just need to add it to the line in your sources.list file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I took the working sources.list from an Azure vm and added it to the end of the existing one, so my updated sources.list is as follows:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
```